# method not allowed wcf rest with Type post

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, rest

i create an application with wcf and rest  ihave a problem with my  operation with Type Post he retourn Method not allowed , this is my operation

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "newContact", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [AuthorizedMethod]
        bool CreateContact(string jsonstring);
```

and in this page i conevert the type string to json

```
public bool CreateContact(string jsonstring)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonstring);

            log();
            return dispatcher.CreateContact(values);
```

and this is my service

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="Mobility.SolutionService.AppService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>          
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:443/B2M/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="crossDomain" 
                  contract="Mobility.SolutionService.IAppService" behaviorConfiguration="Web"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="crossDomain">

          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" >
            </transport>
          </security>
        </binding> 
      </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
         <serviceCredentials>

           <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                    customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Mobility.SolutionService.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator, Mobility.SolutionService"/>
           <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=AuthorityName"/>
          </serviceCredentials>

          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
             <authorizationPolicies>
              <add policyType="Mobility.SolutionService.CustomAuthorizationPolicy, Mobility.SolutionService"/>
            </authorizationPolicies> 
          </serviceAuthorization>

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and then i send the data with js

```
function CreateClient(button){
var strN = document.getElementById('nom').value;
        var str1 = document.getElementById('Phone').value;
        var str2 = document.getElementById('Address').value;
        var str10 = document.getElementById('Credit_Limit_LCY').value;
        var dict = []; 
dict.push(
{
       key:"nom",
       value: strN
},
{
        key:"Phone",
        value:str1
},
{
        key: "Address",
        value:str2
},
{
key:"Credit_Limit_LCY",
value:str10
}
);
var Mydata=JSON.stringify(dict);
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
var geturl;

  geturl =$.ajax({  
 url:"https://10.0.2.2:443/B2M/newContact/",
  data:Mydata,
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType:"json",
   timeout:10000000,  
   cache:false,
   type:'POST',
  beforeSend : function(req) {
             req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 
                   make_base_auth (val1,val2));
        },
   error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) { 
   $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();   

    alert("Error status :"+textStatus);  
     alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);  
     alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);  

   },   
success:function(data) {
   alert("success");
   $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    $.mobile.changePage("contact.html", "fade");
   }
});
   }
```

Can you please help me 
thanks

Comment: Would you please clarify your question/problem?  Thanks for listing your code, but where are you seeing the error?  You said "ihave a problem with my operation with Type Post he retourn Method not allowed", but I wasn't sure where you were seeing the "Method not allowed" error -- in a web browser accessing the service/app?

Comment: yes the service just print Method not allowed in the console

Comment: Can you isolate which method is being referred to?  Unfortunately, it sounds like the problem is with your WCF, which is not my area of expertise (I do lots of jQuery though).  Does your service require authentication/authorization?  If so, perhaps you should try temporarily turning this off to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the following url [REST guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx)

There are several REST attributes missing and you should use an object in stead of a stringified string representing your json object. On the server the framework takes care of that.